# При построчном чтении csv-файла строки, написанные кириллицей, не делятся на элементы списка по разделителю

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Вот мой код:

```
import openpyxl
import csv

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('output.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Лист1']
fin = open('Rep.csv', encoding='utf8' )
reader = csv.reader(fin)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
    print(len(row))
```

Изначальная задача кода была в том, чтобы записать данные из csv-файла в excel-таблицу с использованием списка. Латиницу данный код преобразует в список по разделителям из csv-файла как нужно, а кириллицу - нет: видит все значения как один элемент. Вот, что получается в консоли:

```
['Name', 'User', 'Date started', 'Time spent', 'Time spent(s)', 'Time spent(h)']
6
['Сделать поле Номенклатура" не обязательным для заполнения в заявке на закупку","Павлов Андрей","2019-11-05T06:41:51.864Z",5m 55s,355,0.099']
1
['Удалить полностью все Заявки на закупку, помеченные на удаление,"Павлов Андрей","2019-11-06T05:55:50.456Z",20m 2s,1202,0.334']
1
['Сделать поле Ставка НДС" и "Цена" не обязательным для заполнения","Павлов Андрей","2019-11-06T06:16:14.070Z",30m 15s,1815,0.504']
```

Делать сплит по запятой (изначальный вариант, еще не использовался csv_reader) не получилось, т.к. внутри значения csv-файла уже есть запятые. В результате, таблица получается неверная. Этот код не помог:

```
start_row = 0
for row in fin:
   lst = row.split(',')
   start_row += 1
   for j in range(0, len(lst)):
       actrow = sheet.cell(row = start_row, column = j+1)
       el = lst[j]
       actrow.value = el
wb.save('test2.xlsx')
```

Подскажите, почему так происходит? Как сформировать нормальный список из строк csv-файла?

Пытаюсь считать следующее (так выглядит файл при открытии в python):

```
Name,User,Date started,Time spent,Time spent(s),Time spent(h)
"Сделать поле Номенклатура"" не обязательным для заполнения в заявке на закупку"",""Павлов Андрей"",""2019-11-05T06:41:51.864Z"",5m 55s,355,0.099"
"Удалить полностью все Заявки на закупку, помеченные на удаление,""Павлов Андрей"",""2019-11-06T05:55:50.456Z"",20m 2s,1202,0.334"
"Сделать поле Ставка НДС"" и ""Цена"" не обязательным для заполнения"",""Павлов Андрей"",""2019-11-06T06:16:14.070Z"",30m 15s,1815,0.504"
"Создать объект конфигурации регистр накопления Заявка на закупку"""",""Павлов Андрей"",""2019-11-06T04:41:29.089Z"",2h 6m 30s,7590,2.108"
"Не приходит оповещение исполнителю по заявке на закупку,""Павлов Андрей"",""2019-11-06T10:37:51.860Z"",1h 33m 51s,5631,1.564"
```

Сам файл при открытии в Excel выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос кусок csv, что вы считываете. Еще... есть разные диалекты csv, возможно в вашем csv отличается от стандартного в питоне, можно попробовать автоматически его определять, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2df8235bda5cecd04d5fa246602ed645108d3908/csv__examples/reader_csv__auto_dialect__using_csv_Sniffer.py#L10

Comment: Спасибо, что расширили вопрос :) Только, для вставки кода используйте не javascript-сниппет, а кнопку на панели редактора `{}`

Answer (score 1):

Добавил [автоопределение диалекта](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2df8235bda5cecd04d5fa246602ed645108d3908/csv__examples/reader_csv__auto_dialect__using_csv_Sniffer.py#L10) и разобралось:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.readline())
    f.seek(0)

    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=dialect)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(len(row), row)
```

Консоль:

```
6 ['Name', 'User', 'Date started', 'Time spent', 'Time spent(s)', 'Time spent(h)']
6 ['Сделать поле Номенклатура" не обязательным для заполнения в заявке на закупку""', 'Павлов Андрей""', '2019-11-05T06:41:51.864Z""', '5m 55s', '355', '0.099"']
5 ['Удалить полностью все Заявки на закупку, помеченные на удаление,"Павлов Андрей""', '2019-11-06T05:55:50.456Z""', '20m 2s', '1202', '0.334"']
6 ['Сделать поле Ставка НДС" и ""Цена"" не обязательным для заполнения""', 'Павлов Андрей""', '2019-11-06T06:16:14.070Z""', '30m 15s', '1815', '0.504"']
6 ['Создать объект конфигурации регистр накопления Заявка на закупку"""', 'Павлов Андрей""', '2019-11-06T04:41:29.089Z""', '2h 6m 30s', '7590', '2.108"']
5 ['Не приходит оповещение исполнителю по заявке на закупку,"Павлов Андрей""', '2019-11-06T10:37:51.860Z""', '1h 33m 51s', '5631', '1.564"']
```

В последней строке, похоже, напутали с кавычками-запятыми, поэтому `Name,User` в одной поле попали

---

**PS.**

А по поводу `Excel`, тут кракозябры из-за разной кодировки. Похоже, Excel думает, что там windows-1251 (cp1251). Можно попробовать перекодировать строку `el` перед записью в `actrow.value =` -- привести к байтам из `utf-8`, потом привести к строке как `cp1251`

Comment: `автоопределение диалекта` - спасибо, сегодня выучил что-то новое для себя)